# how many values are missing for each observation

Tags: sas

I have data as follows:

```
ID  date  shoesize shoetype

1   4/3/12  .  bball

2   .    12 running

3 1/2/12  8 .

4 . 9.5 bball
```

I want to count the number of '.' there are in each row and make a frequency table with the information. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: ive already done one way freq tables for all the columns. trying to decide whether to impute or delete

Answer (score 2):

You can determine the number of missing values in a row with the NMISS and CMISS functions (NMISS for numeric, CMISS for character).  If you have a list of just some of your variables, you should use that list; if not, you need to deal with the fact that number_missing itself will be missing (the -1 there).

```
data want;
set have;
number_missing=nmiss(of _numeric_) + cmiss(of _character_)-1;
run;
```

Then do whatever you want with that new variable.

Comment: h/t to user2337871/Scott for pointing out CMISS being necessary given the OP's data.

Answer (score 1):

NMISS doesn't work if you wish to evaluate character variables.  It converts character variables in the list of arguments to numeric which results in a count being made of missing in every instance that a character variable is encountered.  CMISS doesn't convert character variable values to missing and therefore you get the correct answer.

Obviously you can choose not to include the character variables as your arguments, however I am assuming that you want to count missing values in character variables as well, based on the sample you provided.  If this is the case the following should do what you want.

```
DATA WANT3;
SET HAVE;
NUMBER_MISSING = 0;
NUMBER_MISSING=CMISS(OF _ALL_);
RUN;
```

You must allocate a value to NUMBER_MISSING, otherwise the new variable is also evaluated as a missing.

Comment: That wouldn't work for the numeric variables, actually (as they would be converted by default to "." which is not character missing).  Thanks for pointing that out, though.